# Pushing from local repository to GitHub hosted remote

Tags: git, github, git-push

I created a local repository of my Visual Studio 2010 solution folder using Git GUI on my dev machine. I then created a remote repository in my GitHub account. Now, I am looking for how to push my local repository to the remote repository.

In SVN I can just commit using TortoiseSVN and changes are pushed to the remote repository. I don't see any tool like that available for Git.

How do I push my local repo to my remote repo on GitHub?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

You push your local repository to the remote repository using the `git push` command after first establishing a relationship between the two with the `git remote add [alias] [url]` command.  If you visit your Github repository, it will show you the URL to use for pushing.  You'll first enter something like:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git
```

Unless you started by running `git clone` against the remote repository, in which case this step has been done for you already.

And after that, you'll type:

```
git push origin master
```

After your first push, you can simply type:

```
git push
```

when you want to update the remote repository in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to add the remote, but when I run `git remote add ~origin~ master` I get the error: src refspec master does not match any.` What does that mean?

Comment: Are you actually typing '~origin~' or just 'origin'?  You'd best avoid tilde as it means something to Git.

Comment: You should never be running `git remote add origin master`; that's not in my examples and it doesn't make sense as a command.  In all cases when you're reporting an error message, please copy and paste *exactly* what you typed and *exactly* what the response was.  That saves us from having to guess or giving you bad information.

Comment: @larsks I agree. my comment above is inaccurate. I added the remote using Git Gui. I got the error when trying to push `git push ~myrepositoryname~ master`. I assume that `origin` should be replaced with my repository where the project files originate.

Comment: You're putting tildes (`~`) in your example again.  Don't do that unless you're really typing them in on the command line.  Yes, `origin` is the name of your remote (that you created with a `git remote add` command), but if you're calling your remote anything other than `origin` you want to have a really good reason for it (because a variety of tools and guides will assume `origin` without explicit configuration).

Comment: I feel like I should delete all the repos and try again. As I said, when I run that command (git push reponame master) I get that error:  src refspec master does not match any. I don't know what this means. Perhaps I need to create a repository branch called master?

Comment: For me it works with https:github.com/username/repo.git only, I don't know why.

Comment: I had to `git pull origin master` first, then push

Comment: If your repo already has an origin set and it is wrong, you can re-set it with: `git remote set-url origin https://YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME@github.com/YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME/YOUR_GIT_REPO.git`.

Comment: Why cant they explain this in normal docs?  Its like this is a secret or some sh*t.  THANK YOU!

Comment: @RClaven, after you create a new repo on Github, this is clearly explained on the subsequent screen in the section labelled "Push an existing repository from the command line".

Comment: @Renaud If you checked "Initialize this repository with a README", then you likely have to pull first, so your local repo gets that file. Uncheck the box when you create the GitHub repo to rely solely on your already existing repo's files. You should then be able to push without pulling first.

Comment: You can find some answers here: http://gitref.org/remotes/ . In larsks example, origin is an alias for the remote repository git@github.com:username/reponame.git

Answer (score 3):

Type

```
git push
```

from the command line inside the repository directory

Comment: I suppose that would imply using gitbash instead of gitgui?

Comment: Yes, if you're on a system without a fully-featured command line built in then that's something to mention in the question

Comment: no I have that... I'm just somewhat intimidated by command line. Mostly because I just haven't used it much. This'll help change that.

Comment: It may be a steep learning curve but common opinion is that the benefits far outweigh the disadvantages

Comment: Thank you. I didn't want to have to look much longer. The IDE keeps freezing up do to the size.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Subversion implicitly has *the* remote repository associated with it at all times.  Git, on the other hand, allows many "remotes", each of which represents a single remote place you can push to or pull from.

You need to add a remote for the GitHub repository to your local repository, then use `git push ${remote}` or `git pull ${remote}` to push and pull respectively - or the GUI equivalents.

Pro Git discusses remotes here: http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-5.html

The GitHub help also discusses them in a more "task-focused" way here: http://help.github.com/remotes/

Once you have associated the two you will be able to push or pull branches.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for my GIT version 1.8.4:

1. From the local repository folder, right click and select '**Git Commit Tool**'.
2. There, select the files you want to upload, under '**Unstaged Changes**' and click '**Stage Changed**' button. (You can initially click on '**Rescan**' button to check what files are modified and not uploaded yet.)
3. Write a Commit Message and click '**Commit**' button.
4. Now right click in the folder again and select '**Git Bash**'.
5. Type: **git push origin master** and enter your credentials. Done.

Answer (score 0):

open the command prompt 
Go to project directory

type git remote add origin your git hub repository location with.git