# I have error when push/pull git

Tags: git

I am created my exists project from local files. But this project exists in git repository. And now i need commit changes in project and pull/push his, but git don't know what is repository i have master or origin. 
This is error message:

```
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using git from the command line? If yes please add the command you are using in your question.

Comment: This happens, when you push to a some/dir/.git from a remote server, but now how do you get what was pushed into .git from your local machine? Suggestions I saw were: use a 3rd bare repo to synchronize the remote and local repos, don't push directly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you initially cloned your repository then:

```
git push origin master
```

If you are wanting to push local files to an empty repository you created on github, then:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git
```

You have to have a connection established to communicate properly.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10573992/2812723) is a more detailed answer to help.

[Here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) is a good Git tutorial site.

EDIT:
"You push your local repository to the remote repository using the git push command after first establishing a relationship between the two with the git remote add command. If you visit your Github repository, it will show you the URL to use for pushing. You'll first enter something like:

`git remote add origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git` "

Replace `git@github.com:username/reponame.git` with the URL from the repository.  The URL is located on the right side bar, titled "SSH clone URL".

Comment: On gitlab repository existing. But i am not clone repository.

Answer (score 2):

For people whose remotes are already set...

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> <local branch>
```

This would allow you to simply run **"git pull"** instead of **"git pull origin branch"**

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my problem.