# What happens to project with remote library dependency in android studio if maven repository publisher removes his repository

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

For Example you are using this library and sometimes later this library no longer exist in maven so what happens to your project?

Can we be able to continue developing that project using this kind of remote library? or we need to replace codes that uses this library?

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about a [dependency like the above which is in Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh) the dependency will never be deleted in Maven Central, cause you can't delete artifacts in Maven Central.

If the depenedency is comming from somewhere else you might better duplicate the code into your internal system or the best solution would be to use a repository manager which contains every artifact which you ever used and you can backup this system without the need of Maven Central. Thinking of breaking network connections or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest would be to simply clone this library:

```
git clone https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh.git
```

and push it to your github account [Pushing from local repository to GitHub hosted remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573957/pushing-from-local-repository-to-github-hosted-remote)