# How to push a new local repository to old remote repo?

Tags: git, github

I have a remote repo in github. As I am constantly working on to improve my project, I have changed the project structure and added/ deleted few file. Now I want to push this new local project files to remote repo on github. How do I do that? Any example/ explanation would be helpful.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573957/pushing-from-local-repository-to-github-hosted-remote) could be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you simply want to update your remote repo with your changes.

You will need to add and commit your changes, then push upstream to your remote repo, like so:

1) Make sure your upstream points to your remote repo:

```
git remote -v
```

If that does not come back with the url to your upstream repo, set that now:

```
git remote add origin URL_TO_REMOTE_REPO
```

2) Next, add your changes (use `--all` if your want to update EVERYTHING)

```
git add --all
```

3) Now, commit your changes and write a commit message detailing the changes

```
git commit
```

4) Finally, push to your remote repo:

You can push to a branch...

```
git push origin YOUR_BRANCH_NAME
```

Or you can push directly to master like so...

```
git push origin master
```

Note: This assumes that the local directory you are working from has been initialized as a git repository. If it has not, use the command `git init` before you try the above steps.

Comment: If there are remote has changes that you don't have locally, git will reject the push. To get around this you could `pull` first and integrate remote changes or use the `push -f` option to overwrite the remote changes.