# How to push modified files into github project repo

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I really have no clue how to use Git and so far I've only used github.com to upload changes which is not practical.
I'm really confused on how to setup git with android studio and simply push the changes that I make through android studio. The project repo already exists and I cloned it. Then I need to push the modified files into a branch.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: i'd recommend trying to understand git before trying to fit a project into it.  create a new project on github, and just upload one file. follow some tutorials on how to update your file, push changes back up. revert changes, etc.  once you understand it, it will make sense on how to fit it into a whole project, and where SCM's role fits in.  See the link @felixyadomi shared - that's the tutorial i always link people to!  good interactive tutorials there

Comment: Android Studio is just like any text editor. Since you already have your repository, you may want to add your modified files to the stage and commit them, then push to the remote which in your case is github.com. You may take a look at https://try.github.io for how to use git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pushing from local repository to GitHub hosted remote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573957/pushing-from-local-repository-to-github-hosted-remote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, If you `clone` some other repo, you can not `push` it directly from your local machine. You need to `fork` the project first. Then clone it through

```
git clone url
```

after that change some files and add them through

```
git add .
```

Put some commit status there using

```
git commit -m "file changing message"
```

then push it in your repo

```
git push origin master
```

finally send a `pull request` to the author.