# Pushing local repository changes to a Github

Tags: git, github

I am very new to Git

I have the following local directory:
`/c/Users/Emon/Repo_2` and I branched the same to `Repo_2branch`
Now I added some files to this repository `Repo_2` and I want to find the changes in the remote `Repo_2` in my Github account.
I committed the changes and tried pushing it with the command,

```
$  git push --set-upstream origin Repo_2branch
```

But I am not able to see the changes in the remote repository.

What should I do to see the changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573957/pushing-from-local-repository-to-github-hosted-remote

Comment: is your push command was successful? Usually it should be visible within few seconds

Comment: What do you mean *you branched the same to Repo_2branch*? It feels like you have two directories now for the two branch? Git doesn't work that way, if this is the case, you cloned your repository to 2 instances.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pushing from local repository to GitHub hosted remote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573957/pushing-from-local-repository-to-github-hosted-remote)