# GitHub - how to update repo

Tags: visual-studio, github

I downloaded the folder from my Github project and edited it with visual studio. I want to connect this new folder to the same Github repo I downloaded from. Is this possible or will I have to make a new repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pushing from local repository to GitHub hosted remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573957/pushing-from-local-repository-to-github-hosted-remote)

Answer (score 0):

***It's duplicated: [Pushing to Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573957/pushing-from-local-repository-to-github-hosted-remote)***

---

I assume that, you have cloned the repo, didn't downloaded as a .zip.
Everything what you need to know about pushing changes to remote is here: [Github Push](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/). For more detailed view look at here [git-push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

I usually use some GUI for git (TortoiseGit). To do this from a cli you have to write:

```
git push --all
```

After this git will ask you about credentials to you repo. This is really basic way but is good at the beginning.